# Lambda expressions and others not working in Visual Studio 2010. I know it's likely a class library(?) problem but I just can't get it to resolve

Tags: .net, lambda, frameworks, nameof

I am gradually trying to debug a website created by a developer, who's left the company.
I am re-creating the source code, as he does not seem to have checked it in when he left.

I'm using dotPeek, decompiling the bits I think are relevant, then pasting them in to the older code available locally. It seems like a mad thing to be doing, but I can't think of any other way of restoring the code to a state where my local matches the server, and thus could be debugged. (Which isn't working properly btw, a different issue.

Anyway, the code is littered with things like this:

```
source?.Remove(source.Last<HtmlNode>());
```

//(Gives error: Invalid Expression term ".")
and

```
return !this.Request.IsAjaxRequest() ? (ActionResult)this.View(nameof(Upload)) : (ActionResult)this.PartialView("_Upload");
```

//(Gives error: The name nameof does not exist in the current context.
and

```
auditRepository?.Save();
```

//(Gives error: Syntax Error ":" expected).

I understand this is because of a code library issue.

This is a Visual Studio 2010 Project.
In the project properties it says "Target Framework": .NET Framework 4. Output type: Class Library

I'm not sure what to do too make it resolve the "new" code items.
I tried:
 - Changing to a different Framework version (this gave many hundreds of errors).
 - Installing "roslyn" (or trying to) both by trying to use the Package Manager Console (I tried 3 different versions none worked); I've also tried installing it manually by copying the directory from the server.

I saw some suggestions online about adding things to the app.Config (that didn't work) or the web.Config (also didn't work).

Does anyone know how to make the errors go away? I really have to fix them, since I don't know if changing them (for example, by removing the ?) is actually causing other errors.
I also tried installing someone's code to fix the nameof. That didn't work, either, possibly because no example was shown of how to call it.

But I kinda need it to work as coded - I'm already de-compiling it, I don't have time to re-write it in an older (or newer, who knows?) version..

Any ideas? I've run out...

Comment: Have you tried to use a newer version of VS? Elvis operator `?.` is C# 6 feature, I don't think that it will work on VS2010. Try to use VS2015 or 2017/2019 even

Comment: I can try a newer one, each time I do it breaks everything. I read of a way of "compiling the functionality" into older projects. Is that a possibility? Its just two functions the lambda and the nameof? Is someone know where they are I could just add references - e.g. do you know what dll they are in? I'll try opening the project in newer versions now anyway, but usually it breaks everything and takes me back to square one.

Comment: If opened in a newer one:

Comment: Unsupported
This version of Visual Studio is unable to open the following projects. The project types may not be installed or this version of Visual Studio may not support them. 
For more information on enabling these project types or otherwise migrating your assets, please see the details in the "Migration Report" displayed after clicking OK.